# Is it possible to configure Ueberauth to use Github Enterprise for login?

Tags: elixir, github-enterprise, ueberauth

I’ve tried a basic configuration to connect to Github with Ueberauth, but I thought I’d be able to find a configuration to adjust the OAuth endpoints to my Github Enterprise instance, and the documentation doesn’t mention how to do this. I can see the endpoint configuration hard-coded into the module, but I’m unsure what I’d have to do to connect to my Enterprise instance without re-writing the whole strategy.

How can I configure Ueberauth to use my GitHub Enterprise instance instead of Guthub.com?

Comment: I believe you should create your own _strategy_ for _Überauth_ based on [`ueberauth_github`](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth_github) (or maybe [`ueberauth_gitlab`](https://github.com/mtchavez/ueberauth_gitlab).) It should be as easy as clone the repo and alter some settings.

Comment: I was honoring to avoid forking the whole repo just to change a base URL that should be a config option. Alas.

Comment: make the changes and do a PR